# Fedora 20 start script on startup

Tags: linux, fedora, boot, gnome, systemd

I am trying to start a slideshow automatically on startup in Fedora 20. I started with a simple script. eog is "eye on gnome" which is a slideshow viewer and my pictures are in the /home/admin/Downloads directory. This works perfectly.

```
#!/bin/bash
#
eog --slide-show /home/admin/Downloads
```

Next I created a unit file in /etc/systemd/system

```
[Unit]
Description=Starts the pics program

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/admin/pics

[Install]
WantedBy=graphical.target
```

When I tried running the startup script, I got the following

```
Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/pics.service; enabled)
Active: failed (Result:exit-code)...
Process: 4752 ExecStart=/home/admin/pics
Main PID: 4799 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

...:Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
...:Cannot open display:
...:Run 'eog --help' to see a full...
...:Unit pics.service entered failed state.
```

After research, I found that I need to include the following, but no matter where I put it, I keep getting different failures. Apparently it has something to do with running a program as a different user. Can I get some help fixing my code?

```
 pkexec env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY XAUTHORITY=$XAUTHORITY
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Desktop Application Autostart](http://standards.freedesktop.org/autostart-spec/autostart-spec-latest.html) instead.

Inside `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/autostart/` (default: `$HOME/.config/autostart`), create a `pics.desktop` file, that should contain:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=/home/admin/pics
Hidden=false
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
Name[en_US]=pics
Name=pics
Comment[en_US]=Starts the pics program
Comment=Starts the pics program
```

---

If you really want to use systemd units, at least:

- Change process to use non-root UIDs. Graphical apps shouldn't run as root.

  ```
  [Service]
  User=admin
  ExecStart=/home/admin/pics
  ```
- [Inject "correct" environment variables at process.](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd/User#Note_about_X_applications)

  ```
  [Service]
  Environment="DISPLAY=:0"
  User=admin
  ExecStart=/home/admin/pics
  ```